Is it possible to monitor the current drawn by a computer from an outlet on the computer?
Is it possible to monitor the current being drawn by a computer from an outlet using built-in tools like a terminal? I know some systems can report power usage, but if I dynamically reduce the current to a level below the maximum the computer can handle, would I be able to see that current value reported somewhere in the laptop?
If this functionality isn’t built into the system, is there a way I could implement it myself?

No. The computer has no way to measure what the separate power supply is doing. The PS could be 95% efficient, or 70% efficient. The PS regulates output until the input voltage drops too low, so there is no indication what the input voltage is from the PS output.

if you use a UPS, you can usually get info like wattage draw, voltage, etc from its LED screen. some UPS's have client software that lets it do things like record and view history.

It is plausible for full-on servers to tell you how much power each PSU is using, but that depends on being a commercial grade server.  Dell has OpenManage that tells you such things from the commandline, I'm sure HP and Lenovo and Fujitsu and all the other real server can do this.   A cheap desktop or laptop?  Not so much.

Monitoring how much power the computer uses,  while not common, is definitely a thing.  Motherboard monitoring software does this routinely, especially for the CPUs.  This is not technically the same as monitoring the current draw from the outlet to the PSU, but the concept is the same.

In addition to servers, some high-end workstations also have this capability, so if there's a real need for a desktop that can do this there might be a product that will work.

Not without adding hardware.
the TP link kp115 can monitor a single outlet.
The hs300 is an outlet strip with 6 outlets individually monitored.
A python script exist to collect power consumption stats for TP link kasa devices.
These can be monitored from the app on a phone or you could setup external monitoring like homeassistant OS.
A very small number of computer power supplies do offer this feature.  I have a corsair power supply that reports how much power it uses.  Only a few models they make even support this option.
Here is the one I have.  This is a power supply for a desktop PC.

Here it is graphed in homeassistant via kasa hs300


There is no way to tell this accurately without additional hardware as there are no connections from the PSU which send that data (and indeed I doubt its being monitored in the PSU). You may be able to estimate it based on state of charge of the battery and consumption but it will likely be crude.
There must be multiple ways to externally monitor power draw using a device on the input to the PSU. One way would be to use an ESP8266/ESP32 based power controller that includes power draw monitoring. I've had good success using Shelly 1pm devices (https://www.shelly.com/en/products/shop/shelly-plus-1-pm) which can be easily read using http requests and/or MQTT. I have no doubt there are other cheaper brands which do exactly the same thing or can be made to do so using Tasmota - but I use Shelly's because they are easy and permitted in my country. Welcome to the world of IOT devices.
Note there is almost certainly a level of disconnect between your usage and what the battery is doing - so depending on your use case (ie the why) and your hardware this may be an XY problem.  Its noteworthy that USB-C and even many older laptops have a negotiation of maximum charge rate between the laptop and charger - maybe you can take advantage of this and use a lower amp charger that negotiates max charge rate?

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/power-consumption is an interesting read (albeit Linux centric) which canvases the capabilities of what you may be able to do with software depending on your laptop.

There is a device called a "kill a watt", it is useful for getting a good grasp of electricity draw in any 110 outlets.
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=kill+a+watt

This is a link only answer and essentially duplicates information better presented in other answers. Perhaps you intended this to be a comment on one of the other answers? Please read the Help section to learn how to recommend hardware solutions, and how to write good answers in general.

While it is a shorter answer comared to the existing ones, I disagree that it is a duplicate. KaW is a cheap-and-easy device that can provide immediate feedback without the need of any special installation or drivers, unlike the devices suggested in other answers.

"Is it possible to monitor the current drawn by a computer from an outlet on the computer?" - Yes, there's a special kind of device named Kill-A-Watt. This is an answer. And the link is supplementary to that.

I agree this is not a link only answer (but its also not a great answer as it ignores a key part of the question - which is to see the power consumption in the laptop)

I wouldn't call this spam. This specific device is what I use for this purpose. It's extremely common, cheap and hasn't changed in years. A household name, in certain households. Granted, this answer does not say how to actually get that information to your laptop. As an older device, it does not provide that capability, but its simple enough that you can hack it in with some basic Arduino skills.

@jmathew thats a nifty hack, but its not really hacking a kill-a-watt with basic arduino skills - its using the kill-a-watt housing to add an IOT board.  It will likely work out cheaper and definitely much safer and easier to just use an off-the-shelf IOT device to do this.

@davidgo Agreed that a purpose built board would be a safer and cheaper solution.  Perhaps I should've @'d to be clearer, but there was a suggestion that this answer was so low in quality as to be spam, presumably because of the link and brevity. That's mostly what I was rebutting, but I also wanted to add that getting information off KaW was technically possible. Although, I'll concede that "simple" is subjective.
